# Array containing 2Darrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need a container to hold 2D arrays (up to 1000 at most). I'm a bit unsure of which container would be best, as there are several alternatives. What i think would be the best is an array containing the 2D arrays, but is this possible? And if it is, how do I initialize this array?

Comment: If you want add content dynamic, user ArrayList, or use normal 2 by 2 array

Comment: Are you aiming for a 3D array (3 dimensional matrix)?

Comment: As you say _there are several alternatives_. If you have an unknown number of matrices then a `List<MyThing[][]>` would work. If you know how many there are you could use a `MyThing[][][]` and initialise it like any other array - you don't gain much by doing so however.

Comment: Hm, okay. So the best way to go would probably be a list? Is arraylist a good option? I think it would be easier later in my program to have an index where the 2D array is stored, and it's an option (as far as I remember) to insert and remove at a certain index when you use an arraylist.

Comment: If you want to name the lists somehow use a `Map`. Removing items by index in an `ArrayList` is inefficient as is accessing items by index in a `LinkedList`.